# Why do we have use a augmented matrix when talking about affine transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

I was recently trying to wrap my head around linear and affine transformations. I was able to understand linear transformations pretty well but got kinda stuck at affine transformations.

Now, I understand that affine transformations are merely an extension of linear transformations where you can rotate and translate matrices (their graphical representations). After coming this far, I came across "Augmented Matrices." I understand how it works but I dont understand the point of adding an extra dimension.

Essentially, my question is - **Why add an extra dimension to a matrix when you can still translate and rotate without it?**

You must've gotten to know by now that I am an absolute noob, so I'd appreciate a more intuitive answer in combination with a mathematical explanation. Thank you.

Comment: How would you use a matrix to translate a three dimensional vector without the extra dimension?

Comment: Right so you mean, we add extra dimensions to our matrix in case there is a vector of a higher dimension. Correct?

Comment: "Rotation and translation" (and combinations thereof) is not a complete summary of the affine transformations. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "you can rotate and translate **matrices**. You can apply an affine transformation to a vector (which is in a sense a matrix if you think of it as a column vector), but you don't really "apply transformations to" matrices other than column vectors.

Comment: @HarshDarji In any case, you might find the [relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation) to be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You cannot translate with a matrix (linear transform).

If you think of the new dimension as "time", then translation would be represented by a velocity $\vec{v}$ applied to $t = 1$.

Geometrically, you can think of the hyperplane whose $(n+1)$-th coordinate is equal to $1$. Now, you can use the extra $(n+1)$-th vector as the image of $(0,0,0, \dotsc, 0, 1)$.

Algebraically, you are not dealing with $\vec{0}$, because the last coordinate is always $1$. Since it is not $0$, you can send $(0,0,0,\dotsc, 0,1)$ anywhere you want. Also, since the last line of the matrix is $(0,0,0,\dotsc,0,1)$ you never leave the hyperplane.